# wanting a javascript regex notation for replacing cases

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, lowercase

e.g.

I want to write a camelToSnake()

```
camelToSnake = (phrase) ->
  return phrase.replace(/([A-Z])/g, /-\L$1/)
```

is there such options

Comment: No, you can't do like `\L$1` in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var s = 'camelToSnake';
var r = s.replace(/([A-Za-z])/g, function ($0, $1) { c=$1.charAt(0);
          return (c==c.toUpperCase())?c.toLowerCase():c.toUpperCase(); } );
//=> CAMELtOsNAKE
```

Comment: Wouldn't the callback for snake case look more like this? 
function ($0, $1) { c=$1.charAt(0); return '-' + c.toLowerCase() } );
Or am I misunderstanding snake-case? (Also meant to mention the regex would only check upper-case letters)

Comment: That's not true it is just reversing the case so it converts lowercase to uppercase and viceversa.